# Free open source asp.net file managers?

Tags: asp.net, file-manager

Any good ones?
So far I have found IZWebFileManager, OXFileManager and AWS File Picker. The file manager should be able to delete, copy, rename, download & upload files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used [HTTPCommander](http://www.element-it.com/asp-net-explorer-browser/online-share/web-file-manager.aspx). Telerik also has a file manager control in their asp.net suite.

Comment: From what I've seen it's neither free nor open source.

Answer (score 4):

You have [WebFileManager](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WebFileManager.aspx) created by our very own [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood)

Comment: That is written in VB and not exist c# version that is a weakness, in my opinion, Additionally, I see so downvote in the article and I'm not sure to consume time for testing.

Answer (score 2):

(shameless plug)

The question is old, but it may still help someone:

http://elfinderaspnet.codeplex.com/

Uses elFinder as frontend and IHttpHandler as backend so it is compatible with WebForms and MVC.

Comment: It must be so old, In issues page, you can see this question "Looks like it's jQuery 1.8 related:" And this answer "Maybe try with older jQuery (1.7.1)?"

Answer (score 1):

Try here this manager, it can to you will approach.
http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/?CrossDomain

Comment: That is amazing but not free.